# Smoothly Sprite Rotation

Tags: c#, rotation, xna, sprite

I'm writing a game using C# and XNA. I'm trying to smoothly sprite rotation. Here is my code:

```
 protected void RotateSpriteTo(int rotateTo)
    {

        if (rotateGradus > 360)
            rotateGradus = 0;

            if (rotateTo > rotateGradus)
            {
                while (rotateTo > rotateGradus)
                {
                    rotateGradus += 1;
                    rotate = (rotateGradus * (float)Math.PI) / 180;
                }
            }
             else
            {
                while (rotateTo < rotateGradus)
                    rotateGradus -=1;
                rotate = (rotateGradus * (float)Math.PI) / 180;
            }
    }
```

And how I call this method, for example:

```
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            squarePosition.X -= speed;
            RotateSpriteTo(180);
        }
```

But sprite rotates instantly. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantly rotating 180 degrees, try doing this over a period of 3 seconds (aka.

```
RotateSpriteTo((180/3) * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime);
```

Also, you may want to use MathHelper.ToRadians instead of '(float)Math.PI) / 180'. Not saying it doesn't work, but you might as well use the built-in functionality, now that it's there.

Comment: For that to work you'll need to change the method signature to `void RotateSpriteTo(float rotateTo)`

Comment: Oh, true, my bad. Either RotateAmount, which would increase a value, or store a local value that would be incremented by the parameter in my answer.

Comment: Agreed.  Though I still like your correct use of `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime` as a _scalar_. :)